# Sax parser which stops in the first new line

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, sax

I'm working on an android project, and i've found some difficulties parsing an xml file (located in res/raw). I use as a parser " Sax" but I didn't get the whole text between nodes, it stops in the first new line found.
I've tried several tips but in vain, So i'm asking for your help, i hope solving problem asap bescause I feel a huge pressure and i must finish project on time, Thanks a lot.
I've joined my source code : http://www.ensak-entreprises.com/XMLParsing.rar

Answer (score 1):

This page : [IBM Developer Library notes on XML parsing on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) has a very good explanation and code examples for XML parsing on android. I'd recommend using `XmlPullParser` provided by android.